# Printing something in Java after a certain amount of time has passed

Tags: java, timer

I'm working on a text adventure game for my Java class, and I'm running into a problem while trying to time a print statement from showing up in the console.

Basically after 45 seconds I would like a print statement to show up, in this case the print statement would be reminding the user that they need to let their virtual dog out...

I also need the timer to reset after the user gives the correct command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

...

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
   @Override  
   public void run() {
       System.out.println("delayed hello world");
   }
},  45000);
```

[Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Timer.html)

[TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TimerTask.html)

To cancel the timer, either use a TimerTask variable to remember the task and then call its cancel() method, or use `timer.purge()`; the latter cancels all tasks on the timer.  To schedule the task again, just repeat.

You'll probably want to do more advanced operations in the future, so reading the Timer API docs is a good idea.

Comment: Or if you are using Java 8: `timer.schedule(() -> System.out.println("hi"), 45000);`

Comment: When I run this the timer thread keeps running after execution. Do you need a timer.cancel() inside run()?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
       System.out.println(" let the virtual dog out ");
    }
  }, 45000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running in a new Thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.sleep(45000);
        System.out.println("My message");
    }
})
.run();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the thread to sleep for 45 seconds, there is a tutorial here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: Yes and no. OP would need to create separate thread with this task and make him sleep for 45sec. For such case `Timer` class is easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the main thread to sleep might not be ideal as it will cause your program to basically stop. Use a another thread(need to do a little multi-threading) for timing your output and do a check if the message should be printed after the 45s.